# Binding MedialElement from the view (xaml) to a ViewModel's property

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, mvvm, mediaelement

I'm trying to make a binding of a medialElement from MainView.xaml to a ViewModel's proprety.
in MainViewModel.cs we would find

```
#region Media
private MediaElement media;
    public MediaElement Media
    {
        get
        {
            return media;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == media)
                return;
            media = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Media");
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

I would like to know what to put in the MainView.xaml to do the binding.

I know that if it were a TextBox I would write

```
`<TextBox Text="{Binding BGToSet, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />`
```

But what should i do for MediaElement ?
i now do this :

```
`<MediaElement  VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="700" LoadedBehavior="Manual" Height="450" Stretch="Fill"  MediaOpened="{ Binding mediaMediaOpenedCommand}" >
```

`
Thanks a lot for your answer !! Sorry for my english. i'm also new in WPF

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should either expose `Uri` of media source you want to show instead of `MediaElement`:

```
public Uri MediaSource { get { /* ... */ } set { /* ... */ } }

<MediaElement Source="{Binding MediaSource}" />
```

or use `ContentControl` (or `ContentPresenter`) to show `MediaElement` itself:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Media}" />
```

Comment: (thanks for your answer)   First solution :I prefer to keep public _italic_ **bold** `MediaElement Media` because i use it in the MainViewModel.cs in other methods.
Second solution: This solution is apparently the best in my case, but I'm not sure that i understood it, wen i try it i have this:       Error 7 The type 'MediaElement' does not support direct content.

Comment: Remove `MediaElement` from XAML and replace it with `ContentControl`, don't just add `ContentControl`.

Comment: You are certainly clear in your explanation but I am confused: if I use `ContentControl` instead of mediaElement how can I make a binding for the command ` mediaMediaOpenedCommand`?
Here what was my code:

`<StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Background="#64213131" >
                         <Grid AllowDrop="True"    Drop="{Binding WindowDropCommand}">
                                  <TextBlock  > Glisser et déposer une vidéo sur cet écran </TextBlock>
                                 <MediaElement  LoadedBehavior="Manual" MediaOpened="{Binding MediaOppenedCommand " /></Grid></StackPanel>`

Comment: Here what i think i must do :
`<StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Background="#64213131" >
                         <Grid AllowDrop="True"    Drop="{Binding WindowDropCommand}">
                                  <TextBlock  > Glisser et déposer une vidéo sur cet écran </TextBlock>
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Media}" VerticalAlignment="Center"  MediaOpened="{Binding MediaOppenedCommand " />
                        </Grid>
     </StackPanel>`
Thank you very much Max!!

Comment: You can't bind properties of `MediaElement` in XAML if you use second solution. Use view model code to do that since it is already creating `MediaElement`. Also, `MediaOpened` is an event and you can't bind that to command directly, but you can subscribe to it whenever you create `MediaElement`.

Comment: Ok, thanks.
Just one more thing please: whats the name of the function to subscribe the MediaOpened after creating the MediaElement? Ones again: Thanks !!!

Comment: After creating `MediaElement`, use `Media.MediaOpened += OnMediaOpened` and add function to handle event: `void OnMediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { /* ... */ }`

Comment: +1 would not of thought to use ContentPresenter here.